# Looking for a free S&P 500 data feed

Tags: yahoo-finance, feed, google-finance, datafeed

I am looking for a free S&P 500 data feed, preferably one with a REST API.  It appears that Yahoo Finance & Google Finance have discontinued their feeds.  For example, http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG+AAPL&f=snl1 returns, "It has come to our attention that this service is being used in violation of the Yahoo Terms of Service..."  Does anyone know of a free S&P 500 data feed?  Delayed quotes are fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Python combined with Beautifulsoup you can easily get data from multiple sites. Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/A?p=A"
content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
soup = soup.find_all('script')
soupstr = str(soup)
print soupstr[soupstr.find("regularMarketPrice")+27:soupstr.find("regularMarketPrice")+35]
```

The only problem is you will actually use 0,4 MB per quote which I think is a lot of unnecessary use of bandwith and capacity.

Or maybe you can use Quandl.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, @Wietse-de-wit.  I was hoping that I didn't have to resort to screen scraping, but it will work.  Thanks for mentioning Quandl.  I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

So far, I have come across [Alpha Vantange](https://www.alphavantage.co/) and [Tradier](https://developer.tradier.com/). At a cursory glance, Alpha Vantage appears to offer semi-realtime quotes by providing high & low quotes over an interval (1 min is the smallest interval).

Tradier appears to offer free delayed quotes for a "sandbox" environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (took from yFinance source code ):

`https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/%5EGSPC`

I'm not sure if the current price is comming in this response.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Try it for gold too! https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/GC=F

Answer (score 0):

I wound up using IEX Cloud (e.g. https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/TSLA/quote?token=xxxx).  You can sign up for a free account here - https://iexcloud.io.  Lastly, here's their terms of use - https://iexcloud.io/terms.